# Have a class extending Text StatelessWidget be StatefulWidget

Tags: flutter, dart

*I know that in Flutter composition is preferred over inheritance but for one use case I need my class to extend `Text`, since parameter only accepts `Text` classes & not all `Widgets`*

Thing is I need to deal with States in this new class there for I was wondering if I can have

this `class NeedsToBeStateful extends Text {}` be something of `Text extends StatefulWidget` rather than `class Text extends StatelessWidget`

I would also need the `Text` `data` to be updated by the State

```dart
class NeedsToBeStateful extends Text {
  NeedsToBeStateful(
    {super.data = dataUpdatedByState}
  );

  @override
  Text build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(
      data,
    );
  }
}
```

I was thinking of doing something like this but it didn't work

```dart
class NeedsToBeStateful extends Text with StatefulWidget{
  NeedsToBeStateful(
      {super.data = dataUpdatedByState}
  );

  @override
  Text build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(
      data,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I would think it's not possible. But I'm not 100% sure. I'm also curious if there would be a way to do this

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this works or if it's something you can work with, but maybe something like this is possible

```
class MyText extends Text {
  MyText(super.data);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MyState(child: super.build(context));
  }
}

class MyState extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget child;
  const MyState({Key? key, required this.child}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyState> createState() => _State();
}

class _State extends State<MyState> {
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return widget.child;
  }
}
```

Comment: this would work but I would need the Text data to be updated by the StatefulWidget - any Ideas ? : )